# A loop inside a loop

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB for part of my final year project. I am solving a geometric series such as the sum of x^j, starting from j=0 up to n-1. I have the following code so far:

```
$Variable dictionary
%N Number of terms to sum
%alpha Sum of series
%x Vector of constants 
%n Loop counter

N = input('Enter the number of terms to sum: ');
alpha = 0;
x = [0.9 0.99 0.999 0.9999 0.99999 0.999999];
for n = 0:N-1
alpha = alpha + (x.^(n));
end
format long
alpha
```

I want to be able to put the value of `n` in myself and to be able to input more than value of `n`. Is it possible to do a loop inside a loop for this? For example declare `N` as a vector then use the for loop I currently have inside it?

Answer (score 2):

This code would work with string input -

```
N = input('Enter the number of terms to sum: ');
N = str2num(N);
```

Rest of the code stays unchanged.

Enter input as a string, i.e. as an example -

```
Enter the number of terms to sum: '2 5 8 11 14 17'
```

Comment: Thankyou for this however when I amend my code its only throwing up values for n = 10?